# Spring boot: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, spring-boot

i wanna read a json data and then save it to my postgres db, but i got  the message:

No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 0]

Mi files are:
Entity: Visita.java

```
package pe.com.carsa.sintec.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "cobranzas", name = "tb_visita")
public class Visita {

    @Column(name = "motivo", length = 100, nullable = true)
    private String motivo;

    @Column(name = "pv_codigo")
    private int pvCodigo;

    @Column(name = "posicion_inicio", length = 25, nullable = true)
    private String posicionInicio;

    @Column(name = "dni", length = 15, nullable = true)
    private String dni;

    @Column(name = "efectiva", nullable = true)
    private boolean efectiva;

    @Column(name = "u_nombre", length = 150, nullable = true)
    private String uNombre;

    @Column(name = "en_zona_cliente", nullable = true)
    private String enZonaCliente;

    @Column(name = "pv_cliente", length = 255, nullable = true)
    private String pvCliente;

    @Column(name = "fecha_hora_fin", nullable = true)
    private Date fechaHoraFin;

    @Column(name = "duracion", nullable = true)
    private Time duracion;

    @Column(name = "fecha_hora_inicio", nullable = true)
    private Date fechaHoraInicio;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_visita", nullable = true)
    private long idVisita;

    @Column(name = "en_zona_vendedor", nullable = true)
    private boolean enZonaVendedor;

    @Column(name = "tiempo_muerto", nullable = true)
    private Time tiempoMuerto;

    @Column(name = "sin_finalizar", nullable = true)
    private boolean sinFinalizar;

    @Column(name = "comentario", length = 255, nullable = true)
    private String comentario;


    public Visita() {
    }

    getters and setters...
}
```

VisitaService.java

```
package pe.com.carsa.sintec.service;

import java.util.List;

public interface VisitaService<Visita> {

    public Iterable<Visita> list();

    public Iterable<Visita> save(List<Visita> visitas);
}
```

VisitaServiceImpl.java

```
package pe.com.carsa.sintec.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import pe.com.carsa.sintec.entity.Visita;
import pe.com.carsa.sintec.repository.VisitaRepository;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class VisitaServiceImpl implements VisitaService<Visita> {

    private VisitaRepository visitaRepository;

    @Autowired
    public VisitaServiceImpl(VisitaRepository visitaRepository) {
        this.visitaRepository = visitaRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Visita> list() {
        return visitaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Visita> save(List<Visita> visitas) {
        return visitaRepository.saveAll(visitas);
    }
}
```

VisitaRepository.java

```
package pe.com.carsa.sintec.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import pe.com.carsa.sintec.entity.Visita;

public interface VisitaRepository extends JpaRepository<Visita, Long> {
}
```

SintecApplication.java

```
package pe.com.carsa.sintec;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import pe.com.carsa.sintec.entity.Visita;
import pe.com.carsa.sintec.service.VisitaService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SintecApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(SintecApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(VisitaService visitaService) {
        return args -> {
            String url = "XXX.YYY.ZZZ.MMM:1234/path/path/site.action?codCuenta=1&codCampana=1&fechaInicio=2018/10/05  00:00:00&fechaFin=2018/10/06  00:00:00&idUsuarioInvoca=1";
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<List<Visita>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Visita>>() {};
            InputStream inputStream = typeReference.getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
            try {
                List<Visita> visitas = mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);
                //List<Visita> visitas = (List<Visita>) mapper.readValue(url, Visita.class);
                visitaService.save(visitas);
                System.out.println("===SE GUARDO CON EXITO");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("***ERROR: NO SE PUDO GUARDAR LA DATA");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And this is the json data:

```
[{"Motivo":"","pv_CODIGO":"1942645","PosicionInicio":"-11.858479,-77.1199","pv_DNI":"76409500","Efectiva":true,"u_Nombre":"OSCAR SANTAMARIA","EnzonaCliente":false,"pv_CLIENTE":"NOMBRE ; EDAD | JHONATHAN GUILLERMO  CARRANZA ROJAS ; 21","FechayHoraFin":"2018/10/05 08:15:00","Duracion":"00:00:33","FechayHoraInicio":"2018/10/05 08:14:00","idVisita":470761,"EnzonaVendedor":true,"TiempoMuerto":"00:00:00","SinFinalizar":false,"Comentario":""},{"Motivo":"","pv_CODIGO":"1723903","PosicionInicio":"-11.858643,-77.11976","pv_DNI":"43893067","Efectiva":true,"u_Nombre":"OSCAR SANTAMARIA","EnzonaCliente":false,"pv_CLIENTE":"NOMBRE ; EDAD | LEYDY MARIA PALOMINO JULCA ; 32","FechayHoraFin":"2018/10/05 08:16:00","Duracion":"00:00:22","FechayHoraInicio":"2018/10/05 08:15:00","idVisita":470762,"EnzonaVendedor":true,"TiempoMuerto":"00:00:47","SinFinalizar":false,"Comentario":""},{"Motivo":"","pv_CODIGO":"1912759","PosicionInicio":"-11.85855,-77.1198","pv_DNI":"47600923","Efectiva":true,"u_Nombre":"OSCAR SANTAMARIA","EnzonaCliente":false,"pv_CLIENTE":"NOMBRE ; EDAD | ORALDO  IPUSHIMA ARIRAMA ; 36","FechayHoraFin":"2018/10/05 08:17:00","Duracion":"00:00:32","FechayHoraInicio":"2018/10/05 08:16:00","idVisita":470763,"EnzonaVendedor":true,"TiempoMuerto":"00:00:28","SinFinalizar":false,"Comentario":""}]
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: This is your service url
            String url = "XXX.YYY.ZZZ.MMM:1234/path/path/site.action?codCuenta=1&codCampana=1&fechaInicio=2018/10/05  00:00:00&fechaFin=2018/10/06  00:00:00&idUsuarioInvoca=1";

Do you got response from this url? Your question is not clear, is it json parse issue or url call issue?

Comment: when i use postman, i've got response, i can see data. I need save in my db the json data from that url. But, this code obtain: "No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 0]"